# Access controls from other classes

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have 3 classes and they are defined as **public partial class**. First class is **MainWindow**, it is used as a main class, which reference to other classes. Here is the short code:

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="LoginWindow.xaml">
```

Next class is **LoginWindow**, it define WebBrowser control and button, which reference to Last class.

Last class works with WebBrowser, which is in LoginWindow. So if I want to work with WebBrowser, it throws me an error, because that WebBrowser is in **LoginWindow** and i don't have access to it because I´m in Last class. So, is there any way to work with WebBrowser control from another class and have still same data in it? Please, can you write me, how can i do it or post me some link? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: if you are using mvvm you can register `LoginWindow` viewModel instance with your IoC container and then inject it to the third class constcructor.

Comment: ... And if you're not using MVVM please use it.

Comment: I never work with MVVM, I´m in programming new. Is there another option?

Comment: @Facedown as HighCore suggested you really should start thinking about mvvm. there is a learning curve but its definetly worth it. Regardless, you can use DI container to solve your problem even without using mvvm. Check out this post : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137968/Dependency-Injection-in-WPF-using-Unity-for-Dummie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using Prism and Unity IoC container

in your Bootstrapper when you configure the container

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        this.Container.RegisterInstance<LoginWindowViewModel>(new LoginWindowViewModel());
    }
```

In your third view model inject it through the constructor :

```
public class ThirdWindowViewModel
{
    public ThirdWindowViewModel(LoginWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

you can also use the `Resolve` method to get it

`Container.Resolve<LoginWindowViewModel>();`

You can still use Unity as a dependency injection container even without mvvm.

Check out this post : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137968/Dependency-Injection-in-WPF-using-Unity-for-Dummie

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will definitely read it. Once more, thank you :)